# Checking http referrer from ajax call...plus could I return a javascript file name after checking?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, http, referrer

We want to host page elements on our site that 3rd party approved vendors can access for use on their site.

In my tests, I'm using JSONP to go cross-domain to send back JSON through PHP. It is working.

My question is two fold:

1.) When I make the client-side AJAX call in jQuery through a .GET, can I check for the http referrer on the server-side? I'm using PHP for testing, but most likely the live version will be in PERL. We're using white-validation, thus there is an array of approved vendors that I will check against. Do I need to use POST to get the referrer or can I pass it through the .GET?

2.) If they are an approved vendor, then I want to return the JSON with the page elements. Because the JSON is a little lengthy, is there a way instead of sending back the encoded JSON, to send back a javascript file name containing the JSON that I can parse against?

In other words, I would return the file name.

Answer (score 1):

use the `$_SERVER('HTTP_REFERER')` to get the referres address in php. Yo dont need to `POST` or `GET` or anything, enough a simple request.

php can inclde files as content, so you dont need to response a filename, you can response the file. no complication.

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
include('/files/json/filename.json');
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't want to parse the json in php, I want to return it back after the validation to the client side. Will your example do it?

Comment: I guess I can't press my luck and ask how to do this in PERL? Unfortunately, the servers this is going on doesn't have php but perl.

Comment: I don't either so don't feel bad :-)